# Removing headers in Chrome extension with Manifest V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that removes a header from websites that are submitted by the user.

The extension worked in manifest v2 but doesn't work for v3, although I made the necessary changes I have found in the docs to convert to service workers.

code:

background.js

```
// Background.js - JavaScript for background script

// Define a declarative net request rule to modify response headers
const rule = {
  id: 1, // Unique ID for the rule (use an integer, not a string)
  priority: 1, // Priority of the rule (use an integer)
  action: {
    type: 'modifyHeaders', // Action type to modify response headers
    responseHeaders: [
      {
        header: 'X-Frame-Options', // Header name to modify
        operation: 'remove', // Operation to perform (remove the header)
      },
    ],
  },
  condition: {
    urlFilter: '<all_urls>', // Apply this rule to all URLs
    resourceTypes: ['main_frame'], // Apply this rule to main frame resources
  },
};

// Add the declarative net request rule
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({ removeRuleIds: [1] }, () => {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    console.error('Error updating rules: ' + chrome.runtime.lastError);
  } else {
    console.log('Rule updated successfully');
  }
});
```

manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0",  "description": "Open multiple websites in new tabs when you start a new tab",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "BrowserUnicorn",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

I tried to make the Background.js script to remove the X-Frame-Options requests to make the iframes visible inside the chrome extension.

It seems like it doesn't get the job done, because those still refuse to connect.

Comment: urlFilter syntax doesn't support `<all_urls>`. Either remove urlFilter or use '*'.

Comment: because your frame is not a main frame is a sub frame -->> "resourceTypes": ["sub_frame"]